# Unable to create/activate paypal plans in .net core

Tags: .net-core, paypal, paypal-sandbox

In pluralsight course play-by-play-get-paid-dot-net-core-modern-payment-gateways i am trying to replicate the paypal subscription but unable to get paypal plan id because create/active plan fails. Using nuget package paypal 2.0.0-beta00. I have also updated client id and secret.

> SerializationException: Expecting element 'root' from namespace ''.. Encountered 'None' with name '', namespace ''.

```
    private async Task SeedBillingPlans()
    {
        var client = _clientFactory.GetClient();

        foreach (var plan in BillingPlanSeed.PayPalPlans(
            Url.Action("Return", "Subscription", null, Request.GetUri().Scheme),
            Url.Action("Cancel", "Subscription", null, Request.GetUri().Scheme)))
        {
            // Create Plan
            var request = new PlanCreateRequest().RequestBody(plan);
            var result = await client.Execute(request);
            var obj = result.Result<Plan>();

            // Activate Plan
            var activateRequest = new PlanUpdateRequest<Plan>(obj.Id)
                .RequestBody(GetActivatePlanBody());
            await client.Execute(activateRequest);

            // Add to database record
            var dbPlan = _dbContext.BillingPlans.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                x.Name == obj.Name);

            if (dbPlan != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPlan.PayPalPlanId))
            {
                dbPlan.PayPalPlanId = obj.Id;
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Project source: github.com/bjcull/BeerPal

Comment: I have no idea what your error means or is caused by, but I can tell you to not use that SDK. It does not support the new Subscriptions API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/ --- instead, use direct HTTPS API calls

Comment: Can you suggest a step by step guide of doing so, the internet is so vague when it come to paypal integration in .net core

Comment: The examples there use curl, so you will need to implement HTTPS call equivalents in .net